# Django: user.has_perm always true and user is not superuser. Why?

Tags: django, permissions, django-1.5

I assigned a permission of a user in my Django 1.5 app. 
When I list all user permissions with

```
In [1]: user.get_all_permissions()
Out[1]: set([u'profile.change_profile'])
```

I can see one permission (which is correct and wanted). The user is also not a superuser, not an admin.

```
In [2]: user.is_superuser
Out[2]: False
```

However, if I try to use `user.has_perm`, I  always get `True` as a return for any submitted permission request.

```
In [3]: user.has_perm('random_permission')
Out[3]: True
```

A behaviour I would expect if the user is a superuser/admin. Why is a non-superuser getting always `True` for every request? Did I miss any setting?

Comment: Are you using a custom `User` model or Authentication Backend? Maybe read up on the docs here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/customizing/#handling-authorization-in-custom-backends

Answer (score 6):

As mentioned in comment by Thane Brimhall you should check your authentication backends.
You can find this comment on has_perm method of User model in [django sources](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/auth/models.py):

> Returns True if the user has the specified permission. This method
>           queries all available auth backends, but returns immediately if any
>           backend returns True. Thus, a user who has permission from a single
>           auth backend is assumed to have permission in general.

Also don't forget to check user groups. Default backend checks for user groups permissions thus it may be connected.